# How to update a local SQLite database when firestore gets updated in Android studio?

Tags: firebase, sqlite, android-studio

I'm new in using firestore databse and its confusing how to update my sqlite database every time I put data in firestore using the register activity from Android Studio. Need help in how to store the data from firestore to sqlite databse every time the firestore saved data. Sorry my English is not quite good hope you understand me, I hope you can give me some insights or idea on how can I do this for my project

This is the data I want to store to my SQLITE [image: Firestore Data]

And this is where I want to save my data in SQLite
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to store data in SQLite when firestore gets new data? There is an option with Firestore to cache the data locally on device (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#kotlin+ktx)

Comment: I only uses firestore to connect the 2 users of the app backend, but I use SQLite to do complex queries.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will defently help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp). This [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5) will also help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RoomJetpackCompose).